# Translate row in Python to JavaScript: [(M[i], k // M[i])]

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to translate the following script into JavaScript. There is one row which I have no idea what it does, I'm suspecting push to the array.

```
def greedyCoinChanging(M, k):
    n = len(M)
    result = []
    for i in xrange(n - 1, -1, -1):
        result += [(M[i], k // M[i])] // <-- what the hell is this in JavaScript?
        k %= M[i]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you don't have to use a tuple.  You can just use an array.

```
result.push([M[i], Math.floor(k/M[i])]);
```

Also, the integer division (`//`) can become `Math.floor(k/M[i])`;

Comment: Ah, flooring it was. Thanks!

Comment: No Problem. @KarlMorrison

Comment: @KarlMorrison I'm not sure what that edit was, but it made the `[` unbalanced.

Comment: Ahh, you were missing a [, I thought you did it by mistake, my bad!

Comment: No problem at all.